# Invoke multiple build scripts from single build script ? build.xml

Tags: java, xml, ant, build.xml

I have 3 build scripts, each creates a jar file.

- build1.xml -> build1.jar
- build2.xml -> build2.jar
- build3.xml -> build3.jar

How to call all these build scripts from a single build.xml ?

Tried below script(build.xml), but it always calling only 1 script (build1.xml) and creates build1.jar and flow exit. Not processing other 2 build scripts (build2.xml and build3.xml).

Please suggest.

```
<project name="Message Broker Build - DOCGEN" default="all">

<import file="build1.xml"/>
<import file="build2.xml"/> 
<import file="build3.xml"/>


<target name="all" depends="build1, build2, build3"></target>

</project>
```

Comment: Do the target names in build1.xml - build2.xml - build3.xml have different names? Can you show the content of these files as well?

Comment: Have you tried running the files via an [ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `apache ant` on other script files using the [ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html).

```
<ant antfile="build1.xml" />
<ant antfile="build2.xml" />
<ant antfile="build3.xml" />
```

A `target` within each file can be specified with the `target` option.